# How to get all Wikipedia article titles with MediaWiki API?

Tags: mediawiki-api

I know you can get all titles from Wikipedia's [Database dump](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-all-titles-in-ns0.gz) and that you can query for [specific titles](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Allpages), but how can you get them all through the MediaWiki API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all Wikipedia article titles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40825022/how-to-get-all-wikipedia-article-titles)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For that you would use the [Allpages API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Allpages):

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=allpages&aplimit=max
```

You will not get all at once but up to [500 at a time](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&format=json&aplimit=500) and then a continuation marker which you can use for [next batch of titles](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&format=json&aplimit=500&apcontinue=%22Cochise%22_(cyclist)). Continue this until the JSON does not have `query-continue` in the beginning of the answer.

Comment: Is Allpages really an API? Furthermore, I already linked to Allpages so it's not a question of what to use but how to use it.

Comment: Yes, it is. I added examples so that you can see how you can use it.

Comment: Okay thanks, will have to solve this problematically then. Too bad you can't fetch them all with one query, though I can understand Wikipedia not wanting people constantly querying for +64 gigabytes...